# array.every() with type checking doesn’t work consistently

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `Array.every()` with `typeof()` to see if at least one element has a non number

Below is the code snippet

1.

```
[2, "text", 2].every(val => console.log(typeof val ==="number"));// returns true
```

2.

```
["two", "text", 2].every(val => console.log(typeof val ==="number")); //returns false
```

I was expecting 1 and 2 above to return false. Do we know why having a `number` as the first item influences the outcome?  Is there a different way to achieve the same outcome

Comment: The callback should return a boolean value. You are returning the return value of `console.log` which is `undefined`. Both return `false`. What happens is that **`.every` stops immediately when it gets a falsy value**. `undefined` is `falsy`, so the callback is always only executed for the first value in they array. I.e. it is equivalent to 1) `console.log(typeof 2 ==="number")` and 2) `console.log(typeof "two" ==="number")`.

Comment: If it was checking every element in the array you would get three log outputs for both calls. So yes, you do get different outputs because `console.log(typeof val ==="number")` only runs for the first element of each array and those are of different types.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for unexpected results is that you're logging in the wrong place.

The [`Array#every()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns true if all elements in the array satisfy the predicate (callback) that you provide. In the case of you code however, your predicate is returning the result of `console.log` (which is undefined). That means "every" item in the array returns undefined, which in turn means the result of `every()` will be false in both cases.

Something to be aware of is the console will print `true` or `false` when evaluating the expression `console.log(typeof val ==="number")`, so be careful not to confuse this logging with the result of `every()`.

To resolve these expected results, try removing the call to `console.log` from within the `.every()` callback and instead log the result of `every()` like so:

```js
console.log('Expect false for mix of value types:', 
  [2, "text", 2].every(val => (typeof val ==="number")) 
);

console.log('Expect false for mix of value types:',
  ["two", "text", 2].every(val => (typeof val ==="number"))
);

console.log('Expect true for all numbers:',
  [1, 123, 2].every(val => (typeof val ==="number"))
);
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain why the OP sees the output they are getting?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the feedback! Just updated answer :-)

Comment: Great answer! to add to the confusion, the console.log  gets called exactly once per array because of what you explained (returning undefined only evaluates the code once and determines that every should return false) and it may look like it was the return value.